# Update specific user from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just created a user profile page. on my user_model, I have coded this but don't know how am I going to set my controller. I'm just a newbie :D anyone can help? :) thanks in advance

```
public function get_user(){
   $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    return $q->result();
}
public function get_user_byid($u_id) {
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE u_id = '$u_id'");
    return $q->result();
}    
function update_user($u_id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('u_id', $u_id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_userss', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

in my controller

```
      <?php
           if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
                exit('No direct script access allowed');
                  }

    class Profile_controller extends CI_Controller{

         public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->load->library('session');
        }

        public function index(){
            $data['title'] = 'My Profile';
            $data['content'] = 'profile';
            $this->load->view('layout/admin_layout', $data);
        }

         public function update_user_data(){
           $data = array(
               'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
               'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
               'password'=>md5($this->input->post('email')),
               'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
               'mname'=>$this->input->post('mname'),
               'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
               'contact_no'=>$this->input->post('contact_no'),
              'address'=>$this->input->post('address')
           );
           $this->user_model->update_user($data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is in `$data`??

Comment: something like this $data = array(
           'u_id'=>$this->input->post('u_id'),
           'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
           'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
           'password'=>md5($this->input->post('email')),
           'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
           'mname'=>$this->input->post('mname'),
           'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
           'contact_no'=>$this->input->post('contact_no'),
           'address'=>$this->input->post('address')
       );

Comment: In the array remove Id and this code is working fine. So whats your problem??

Comment: what i want is when the user wants to edit their profile, get the active record then update their data from database. I just don't know how am i going to set this in my controller. Sorry

Comment: is this in your controller??

Comment: and by the way, thanks for immediate response :)

Comment: here, i just set this in my controller.
public function update_user_data(){
       $data = array(
           'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
           'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
           'password'=>md5($this->input->post('email')),
           'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
           'mname'=>$this->input->post('mname'),
           'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
           'contact_no'=>$this->input->post('contact_no'),
           'address'=>$this->input->post('address')
       );
       $this->user_model->update_user($data);
    }

Comment: add in your question

Comment: sorry, just new here. how can I add this in my question?

Comment: click on edit in bottom of your question

Comment: I struggle of editing my question but then there, just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
function update_user($u_id, $data) {
    $this->db->where('u_id', $u_id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_userss', $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 ? $u_id : 0;
}
```

EDIT:

url:

POST `http://www.example.com/mycontroller/update_user_data/5`

Controller

```
public function update_user_data($u_id){
$data = array(
    'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
    'password'=>md5($this->input->post('email')),
    'fname'=>$this->input->post('fname'),
    'mname'=>$this->input->post('mname'),
    'lname'=>$this->input->post('lname'),
    'contact_no'=>$this->input->post('contact_no'),
    'address'=>$this->input->post('address')
);

$this->user_model->update_user($u_id, $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

$data should be an array which contains values of user table 'tbl_users', like

$data['name'] = 'User Name';
$data['age']  = '22'; etc.. etc..

Here the terms `name, age` are the fields of table 'tbl_users'

Answer (score 0):

you are sending only one parameter here : `$this->user_model->update_user($data);`
while in your model you are receiving two parameters: `function update_user($u_id, $data){...}`

you never mentioned the `$u_id` while passing it to the model.